# When pushing objects to an array the new object shows up like [[object],[object],[object]] instead of [object, object, object]

Tags: javascript, vue.js, javascript-objects

This is my function:

```
addToCart(id) {
  var productToAdd = this.items.filter(function (item) {
    return item.id === id;
  })
  console.log(typeof(productToAdd));
  this.shoppingCart.push(productToAdd);
}
```

Typeof function indicates that the data type is 'object'. However, the resulting shopping Cart object looks like that meaning the data object was indeed [object].

```json
[
  [
    {
      "id": 2,
      "category": "Snack",
      "name": "Slanty",
      "price": "50",
      "image": "https://www.beautifulworld.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/K2-Mountain.jpg"
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "id": 6,
      "category": "Snack",
      "name": "Slanty",
      "price": "50",
      "image": "https://www.beautifulworld.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/K2-Mountain.jpg"
    }
  ]
]
```

What would be the best way to mitigate this? I need to get my objects in `[{},{},{}]` form instead of `[[{}],[{}],[{}]]`
I know this is not a great question but I'm new to javascript.

Comment: `.filter()` returns an array, if you expect only a single object use `.find(item => item.id === id)` to return just the matching object, otherwise you use `.concat()` instead of push as MetallimaX recommended.

Answer (score 1):

If you use push, you consider pushing a single element. If you want to add the elements of another array, use the [concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) method

Answer (score 1):

You must use `find` instead of `filter`.

```js
addToCart(id) {
  var productToAdd = this.items.find(item => item.id === id);
  if (typeof(productToAdd) !== 'undefined') {
    this.shoppingCart.push(productToAdd);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty straightforward

```
//Assuming that 
 this.items= [ [ { "id": 2, "category": "Snack", "name": "Slanty", "price": "50", "image": "https://www.beautifulworld.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/K2-Mountain.jpg" } ], [ { "id": 6, "category": "Snack", "name": "Slanty", "price": "50", "image": "https://www.beautifulworld.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/K2-Mountain.jpg" } ] ]

this.shoppingCart=[];
this.items.forEach(item => {
 this.shoppingCart.push(item[0]);
});
console.log(this.shoppingCart) // this will be your resultant array
```